# K2 Joomla Wrong Urls in item comments

Tags: php, regex, joomla2.5, joomla-k2

K2 is parsing un-necessary text into urls in item comments.

1.Created a item using joomla admin panel and as a guest entered comment with following text
"node.js is a power full js engine. Enven.though this is not a valid url it has been rendered as valid.url anything with xxx.xxx are parsed as urls and even like sub domain syntax iam.not.valid i.e mail.yahoo.com how funny this is"

1. In the above coomment node.js, even.though, valid.url, xxx.xxx iam.not.valid i.e mail.yahoo.com are rendered as valid url. but in this case only mail.yahoo.com is valid not others.

K2 is using some smart intelligence using following snippet in $JHOME/components/com_k2/views/item/view.html.php lines (159-178)

```
$comments = $model->getItemComments($item->id, $limitstart, $limit, $commentsPublished);
                $pattern = "@\b(https?://)?(([0-9a-zA-Z_!~*'().&=+$%-]+:)?[0-9a-zA-Z_!~*'().&=+$%-]+\@)?(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}|([0-9a-zA-Z_!~*'()-]+\.)*([0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z-]{0,61})?[0-9a-zA-Z]\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})(:[0-9]{1,4})?((/[0-9a-zA-Z_!~*'().;?:\@&=+$,%#-]+)*/?)@";

                for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($comments); $i++) {
                    $comments[$i]->commentText = nl2br($comments[$i]->commentText);
                    $comments[$i]->commentText = preg_replace($pattern, '<a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="\0">\0</a>', $comments[$i]->commentText);
                    $comments[$i]->userImage = K2HelperUtilities::getAvatar($comments[$i]->userID, $comments[$i]->commentEmail, $params->get('commenterImgWidth'));
                    if ($comments[$i]->userID>0) {
                        $comments[$i]->userLink = K2HelperRoute::getUserRoute($comments[$i]->userID);
                    }
                    else {
                        $comments[$i]->userLink = $comments[$i]->commentURL;
                    }
                    if($reportSpammerFlag && $comments[$i]->userID>0) {
                        $comments[$i]->reportUserLink = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_k2&view=comments&task=reportSpammer&id='.$comments[$i]->userID.'&format=raw');
                    }
                    else {
                        $comments[$i]->reportUserLink = false;
                    }
                }
```

Can somebody help fixing above regular expression? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have this problem any time a user types.in a period with no spaces around it. You could add in some login to test for valid TLDs, but even that would not be perfect because there are plenty of TLDs that would fool the logic, like .it.

If you want to try your hand at fixing the regular expression, the pattern that determines if a string is a URL is here -

```
$pattern = "@\b(https?://)?(([0-9a-zA-Z_!~*'().&=+$%-]+:)?[0-9a-zA-Z_!~*'().&=+$%-]+\@)?(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}|([0-9a-zA-Z_!~*'()-]+\.)*([0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z-]{0,61})?[0-9a-zA-Z]\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})(:[0-9]{1,4})?((/[0-9a-zA-Z_!~*'().;?:\@&=+$,%#-]+)*/?)@";
```

Personally, I would just disable links in comments altogether by removing or commenting out this code -

```
$comments[$i]->commentText = preg_replace($pattern, '<a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="\0">\0</a>', $comments[$i]->commentText);
```